# Error: 'std_srvs::Empty' is not a namespace

Tags: ros, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I'm currently working through "A Gentle Introduction to ROS" and in the chapter about services the following example is shown:

```
bool toggleForward(std_srvs::Empty::Request &request, std_srvs::Empty::Response &response){...}
```

Now I don't want to write the std_srvs::Empty:: all the time and I tried the following:

```
using std_srvs::Empty::Request;
using std_srvs::Empty::Response;                                                                     
                                                                                                     
bool toggleForward(Request &request, Response &response){...}
```

But now I'm getting the following errors:

```
error: ‘std_srvs::Empty’ is not a namespace
 using std_srvs::Empty::Request;
                        ^

error: ‘std_srvs::Empty’ is not a namespace
 using std_srvs::Empty::Response;
                        ^
error: ‘Request’ was not declared in this scope
 bool toggleForward(Request &request, Response &response)
                    ^
 error: ‘request’ was not declared in this scope
 bool toggleForward(Request &request, Response &response)
                             ^
 error: ‘Response’ was not declared in this scope
 bool toggleForward(Request &request, Response &response)
                                      ^
error: ‘response’ was not declared in this scope
 bool toggleForward(Request &request, Response &response)
                                                ^
```

I don't understand what's happening here. For example, the following works:

```
using std::cout;
```

What is the difference between those two?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250536/error:-%27std_srvs::empty%27-is-not-a-namespace/) by [jolly](https://answers.ros.org/users/28765/jolly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`std` is a namespace. But `std_srvs::Empty` is a type (in the `std_srvs` namespace), not a namespace itself, so you can't bring `Request` or `Response` out by a `using` declaration.

See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647376) random post on SO that deals with the same issue.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-21**:
And just to clarify: this is obviously not a ROS issue, but a general C++ misunderstanding.

**Comment by [jolly](https://answers.ros.org/users/28765/jolly/) on 2016-12-21**:
I just found the header file for the Empty type and now it's completely obvious for me as well. Thank you.